# Cannot find moodle values in database

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

This might sound stupid, but i'm clueless right now. I'm trying copied the ''page'' module from moodle and restyled it slightly, now I'm trying to access values stored in the database. However I'm unsure how to bring those to display on my page, because I can't even find them in the database itself.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
I noticed I didn't specify that I'm trying to access the module ''settings'' page values.

Comment: This is a copy of the page module? If so you will need to rename everything, including the function names, class names, table names etc. so pagenew or something. It doesn't like underscores either so page_new won't work. Then the module will need to be installed.

Comment: I've already renamed everything and installed the plugin. There aren't any database/syntax errors. I just can't find where my values are stored

Comment: Can you add an instance? Go to a course, turn editing on and add the new page module

Comment: Yep. I can add seperate instances for the page module and for the ''copied'' page module. Also, edited my question

Comment: Okay then the values will be in mdl_pagenew - the name of the table in /mod/pagenew/db/install.xml

Comment: Alright, the page is there. However I'm trying to access some values made in the settings.php of the plugin itself. I cannot see those in the mdl_pagenew table. Any ideas with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings will be in mdl_config_plugins

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_config_plugins
WHERE plugin LIKE '%pagenew%';
```

Comment: Found it, you're an absolute hero. If I can bother you with one more question, is there a way to easily display these values in moodle, or do I have to use an SQL query to retrieve them?

Comment: Yeah they should be under site admin -> plugins -> activities -> manage activities -> then look for your plugin and there should be a settings link - or try the direct link `/admin/settings.php?section=modsettingpagenew`

Comment: Yes, but I need them loaded into a different field on another displaying page. However using something like `get_string("WebServiURL","vidpage")` doesn't display the value that I want